# Custom log level in google logging

Tags: c++, c++11, glog

Is it possible to add custom log level to glog? I couldn't find any examples in their documentation.

Tried to edit glog/logging.h but program is crashing with following bt.

`#0  0x00007f6aacaca1e6 in google::LogMessage::Init(char const*, int, int, void (google::LogMessage::*)()) ()  from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so.0`

`#1  0x00007f6aacac9b13 in google::LogMessage::LogMessage(char const*, int, int) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so.0`

Answer (score 3):

`VLOG(N)` allows you to add your own set of log levels. N is some integer value. The command line flag [`--v=X` will enable logging](https://github.com/google/glog/blob/6fbc93a7e42ee6b8bc5560c06641329134bbf0dc/README.rst#verbose-logging) for all `VLOG` messages at `X` or lower

```
VLOG(10) << "not very important";
VLOG(1) << "maybe a little important";
VLOG(0) << "quite important";
```

You could write your own set of constant integer expressions definitions to pass to `VLOG` rather than using them directly.

Comment: I am trying to add another trace level called "PERF" along with ERROR,INFO,DEBUG,FATAL. exclusively to log performance metrics. is this possible?

Comment: @Nick not without some [heavy lifting](https://github.com/google/glog/blob/ab6545470bdb6fb14442923b2aa3289983bea968/src/windows/glog/logging.h#L502) The api doesn't appear to be designed to support this behavior